# Remapping the gazebo node

Tags: ros, remap, remapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using the following launch file to spawn my robot in gazebo:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find labrob_gazebo)/worlds/second_world.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)" />
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
    <arg name="headless" value="false" />
  </include>


  <!-- urdf xml robot description loaded on the Parameter Server-->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find labrob_description)/urdf/labrob.urdf'" />

  <!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
  <node name="labrob_spawn" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" output="screen" 
    args="-urdf -param robot_description -model labrob" />
</launch>
```

and I want to remap the gazebo node so it will stop using the tf topic.

I have seen this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/229722/how-to-stop-gazebo-publishing-tf/#229735) after DavidN's help, but I would prefer not to modify the launch files of the gazebo_ros package and do the remapping from the launch files I use.

I have tried to create a remap.launch file that I ran after roslaunching the above file, in which I wrote:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="gazebo_ros" name="gazebo" type="gzserver">
<remap from="tf" to="gazebo_tf"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

This didn't work, probably because the remapping can be achieved at the start of the execution of the node and not during runtime.
I have tried to use the `<remap from="tf" to="gazebo_tf"/>` tag almost everywhere in the first file I present here, but the gazebo node doesn't remap from the tf topic -it is not recognized.

How could I modify the first launch file to successfully remap the gazebo node from my package ?

Thank you for your answers and for your time in advance,

Chris

**EDITED:**

The solution proposed by Winston didn't work, because the /gazebo node was already launched initially in the launch file. To be more specific, I got the following errors:

```
roslaunch file contains multiple nodes named [/gazebo].
Please check all <node> 'name' attributes to make sure they are unique.
Also check that $(anon id) use different ids.
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242581/remapping-the-gazebo-node/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-08-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to specify the remapping directly where the gazebo node is started (Internally, the XML-based remapping is converted to arguments provided to the executable). So the one option is to copy the `empty_world.launch` launch file from `gazebo_ros` and add the appropriate remapping, e.g. change [this part](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/indigo-devel/gazebo_ros/launch/empty_world.launch#L30) to:

```
<node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="$(arg script_type)" respawn="false" output="screen"
    args="$(arg command_arg1) $(arg command_arg2) $(arg command_arg3) -e $(arg physics) $(arg extra_gazebo_args) $(arg world_name)">
    <remap from="tf" to="tf_remapped_away" />
  </node>
</node>
```

As another (potential) option, the original `empty_world.launch` also provides a `extra_gazebo_args` argument, that can be used to provide additional arguments. I tried manually adding the remapping there (for my test the `/clock` topic) This however doesn't work, likely due to the duplicate `:=` (would probably need to be escaped somehow):

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch extra_gazebo_args:=/clock:=/clock_remapped_away
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) on 2020-05-16**:
extra_gazebo_args is working for me (for remapping), I have added:

```
<arg name="extra_gazebo_args" value="joint_states:=/turtlebot3_burger/joint_states" />
```

using gazebo_ros empty_world.launch:

```
<!-- Gazebo world -->
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world_path)"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gazebo_gui)"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
    <arg name="extra_gazebo_args" value="joint_states:=/turtlebot3_burger/joint_states" />
</include>
```